# Why is an incorrect template rendered here?

Tags: java, controller, playframework

I'm calling `render()` with a few arguments, the first of which is a `String` argument that I got as a parameter:

public static void action(String url) {
  ...

render(url,...);
}

I'm getting this error:

```
The template http://the.contents.of/urlParameter does not exist.
```

Now, I'm debugging through `render()`, where I see this snippet:

```
protected static void render(Object... args) {
    String templateName = null;
    if (args.length > 0 && args[0] instanceof String && LocalVariablesNamesTracer.getAllLocalVariableNames(args[0]).isEmpty()) {

        // I'm getting into this branch

        templateName = args[0].toString();
    } else {
        templateName = template();
    }
    renderTemplate(templateName, args);
}
```

What is the `if` trying to accomplish? Why am I getting into it - is it because I'm not using a local variable for `url`? Is this documented? What's the reasoning here?

I'm using version 1.2.x-c40cf37 (that's somewhere after 1.2.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you provide a string as the first argument, then it assumes that it is the name of the template to render.

Example:

```
render("@password", url);
```

That will render the password-template and pass the url variable to it.

In your case you could do something like this instead:

```
render("@action", url);
```

EDIT:

As an alternative you could also do something like this:

```
renderArgs.put("url", url);
render();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it does, I didn't know of this. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Weird convention. Certainly doesn't follow the principle of least astonishment - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: I only found it "documented" in the tutorial - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide9

Comment: My actual example had lots of other parameters - I just found a non-String one and made it be the first parameter to `render()`.